# Routing issue in Vue JS 2

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-router

In my project there is a `<router-link>` that directs to a specific page it looks like this

```
<router-link to="menugirl" >Plan your visit</router-link>
```

When you click on the button, this link will be directed to

```
http://localhost:8080/menugirl/category
```

The `category` path that is added at the end of the URL is set by default

And so what is the problem - When I first click on the button and redirect to `http: // localhost: 8080 / menugirl / category`
In this case, this button is present at this address and when I click on this button a second time at `http : // localhost: 8080 / menugirl / category` it already directs `http: // localhost: 8080 / menugirl / menugirl` and I only need it to direct to `http: // localhost: 8080 / menugirl / category`

For a clear understanding, you can look at the demo

```
<router-link to="menugirl" >Plan your visit</router-link>
```

[image]

Comment: If you're going to use a path, make it absolute. Eg `<router-link to="/menugirl">`. I highly recommend using [named routes](https://router.vuejs.org/guide/essentials/named-routes.html) instead

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Not sure if I understood the issue but I think that is enough to add a slash in the beginning of the route like this:

```js
<router-link to="/menugirl" >Plan your visit</router-link>
```